# What's the PHP equivalent of ASP.NET ashx handlers?

Tags: php, asp.net, flash, json, actionscript-3

I need to return a JSON encoded response to a flash http get request.

In ASP.NET, I do this with a ASHX handler.
What's the PHP equivalent ?
I mean in order that I only get JSON back, and not the <html> etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should put this on top of your script:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

- `header('Content-type: application/json');`
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php